# Using Buckets in Google Cloud Platform with Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to host a Go app on the Google Cloud Platform and I need it to do some file writing. GCP doesn't let you do file writing directly in the App Engine, but requires you to use a Bucket.

From their documentation, you can access the buckets in PHP like so

```
$default_bucket = CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName();
$fp = fopen("gs://${default_bucket}/hello_default_stream.txt", 'w');
fwrite($fp, $newFileContent);
fclose($fp);
```

Is there a Golang equivalent for this?

Comment: Indeed: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage

Comment: Are you talking about App Engine Standard or Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shared by Daz on the first comment, there's an intro on how to do this on [the docs for Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). This uses the [`cloud.google.com/go/storage`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage) library, although you could also use the superseded [`google.golang.org/appengine/blobstore`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/blobstore) (as also explained in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/blobstore/)).

With those docs, you could simplify them until you get the following code (tested it and works as expected):

```
package minimal_gcs

import (
        s "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
        a "google.golang.org/appengine"
        h "net/http"
)

func init() {
        h.HandleFunc("/", func(w h.ResponseWriter, r *h.Request) {
                cx := a.NewContext(r)
                c, _ := s.NewClient(cx)
                wr := c.Bucket("<bucket_id>").Object("<object_id>").NewWriter(cx)
                _, _ = wr.Write([]byte("Hello World!!1"))
                _ = wr.Close()
        })
}
```

Note that this is really bad code (no error handling, ...), but I think it's useful to show the basic steps to handle GCS files within GAE standard using Go.